# Paste outputs of two functions to each other in a loop in R

Tags: r, function, lapply

I'm trying to paste the output of `cat` to right after `CrossTable` output. That is, **at each iteration**, first `CrossTable` output comes and right after it, `cat` is generated.

However, I can't achieve that with my current code, is there a way to achieve that in R?

```
library(gmodels)
library(vcd)

z <- data.frame(A = rep(c('Yes','No'), 5), B = sample(c('Yes','No'), 10, replace = T), group = rep(c('Treat', 'Cont'), each = 5))

lapply(names(z)[-3], function(x){ CrossTable(z[[x]], z$group, expected = F, format="SPSS", chisq= T, prop.t = F, dnn = c(x, "Group"));
 cat(paste('cramer =', round(assocstats(table(z[[x]], z$group))[[5]], 3))) #%@ paste to `CrossTable` output
})
```

Comment: You may capture the output  with `capture.output`

Comment: if you need `sink`, then you could use in a `for` loop with `sink` `append = TRUE` for each file

Comment: are you writing this to different files?.  I meant the column1, column2, output goes to different files, right?

Comment: Can you try this `for(i in 1:2) {capture.output(CrossTable(z[[i]], z$group, expected = FALSE, format="SPSS", chisq= T, prop.t = F, dnn = c(i, "Group")), file = "tempnew.txt", append = TRUE); cat(paste('cramer = ', round(assocstats(table(z[[i]], z$group))[[5]], 3)), file =  'tempnew.txt', append = TRUE)}`

Comment: I tried on my end and it is creating the file with all the contents.  Only thing iis how you want it to be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this with a `for` loop after  capturing the output from `CrossTable` and using `append = TRUE` in both `capture.output` and in the `cat` by writing the contents to the same file

```
for(i in 1:2) {
      capture.output(CrossTable(z[[i]], z$group, expected = FALSE,
          format="SPSS", chisq= T, prop.t = F, dnn = c(names(z)[i], "Group")), 
              file = "tempnew.txt", append = TRUE)
     cat(paste('cramer = ', round(assocstats(table(z[[i]], z$group))[[5]], 3)),
           file =  'tempnew.txt', append = TRUE, '\n')
     cat('\n\n\n********************************\n\n\n', 
                  file = 'tempnew.txt', append = TRUE, '\n')
    }
```

-contents of 'tempnew.txt'

[image]

Comment: @rnorouzian have you tried by updating the rstudio  ie.. reinstalling

Comment: @rnorouzian I am not using `windows`, but can you please check if there are any cache's available and remove everything and do a reinstall

Comment: I would remove the temporary files andd if there is any incompatbility with `R 4.0`, then would install R 3.6.2 or so because in windows you can have different R versions installed and then test on it with Rstudio

Comment: I haven't updated my R version to 4.0 as I have to change my laptop next week

Comment: @rnorouzian i think there is  tempfile directory.  I forgot to command to get into that on windows.  Can you please check on google

Comment: @rnorouzian if you need to use devtools, then rtools is needed

Comment: @rnorouzian i am not sure why the rstudio suddenly had an issue.  Have you restarted the system

Comment: @rnorouzian i think there is some issue with rstudio and R 4.0 as somebody else posted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61549557/leaflet-maps-not-working-in-r-studio-after-r-4-0-0-upgrade) question

Comment: Arun, would you be interested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61563303/dataframe-format-change-in-large-dataframes)?

Comment: @rnorouzian do you only need base R

Comment: @rnorouzian i posted a solution there.  Also, it is better to post a small example with expected output so that it can be crossschecked