# dataframe format change in large dataframes in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to make my long format data.frame (5 columns: `"person_id" "item_id" "item_type" "gender" "item_trans"`) into wide format such that each `person` occupies only one row of the data.frame.

I have tried the following without success, is there a quick fix to my code in **BASE R**?

```
dat <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/izeh/n/master/n.csv', stringsAsFactors = F)

reshape(dat, dir = 'wide', idvar = c('person_id','gender'), timevar = 'item_type')
```

Comment: To me it's not very clear what you want to achieve. Could you maybe give a small example of long form and expected wide form data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the OP's clarification, it could be

```
out <- reshape(dat[setdiff(names(dat), 'item_type')], idvar = c('person_id', 'gender'), direction = 'wide', timevar = 'item_id')
dim(out)
#[1]  2000 16006

out[1:3, c(1:3, 16000:16006)]
#   person_id gender item_trans.1 item_trans.15998 item_trans.15999 item_trans.16000 item_trans.16001 item_trans.16002 item_trans.16003
#1          1   MALE     5.091636               NA               NA               NA               NA               NA               NA
#32         2   MALE           NA               NA               NA               NA               NA               NA               NA
#64         3 FEMALE           NA               NA               NA               NA               NA               NA               NA
#   item_trans.16004
#1                NA
#32               NA
#64               NA
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213053/discussion-on-answer-by-akrun-dataframe-format-change-in-large-dataframes-in-r).

Answer (score 2):

### Updated answer with Base R - one row per person

```
dat <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/izeh/n/master/n.csv', stringsAsFactors = F)

# sort the data by person_id, item_type and item_id
dat2 <- dat[order(dat$person_id,dat$item_type,dat$item_id),]

# h/t akrun for ave() approach to generate sequences
dat2$item_seq <- with(dat2, ave(seq_along(person_id), person_id,
                         item_type, FUN = seq_along))
dat2$item_type <- sprintf("%s_%02d",dat2$item_type,dat2$item_seq)
wide_dat <- reshape(dat2, dir = 'wide', drop = c("item_id","item_seq"), 
                    idvar = c('person_id','gender'),
                    timevar = 'item_type')
# clean up column names and print head()
names(wide_dat) <- gsub("item_trans.","",names(wide_dat))
head(wide_dat[1:6])
```

...and the output:

```
> head(wide_dat[1:6])
    person_id gender audio_vocab_01 audio_vocab_02 audio_vocab_03 audio_vocab_04
3           1   MALE      1.5448298      1.6337223      0.4701200     3.04835834
36          2   MALE      3.0483583      3.1066522      3.0483583     3.04835834
64          3 FEMALE      1.6337223      1.6269504      1.0744742     1.62695041
97          4 FEMALE      3.0483583      1.6337223      1.0744742     1.36473950
141         5   MALE     -1.6627051      0.6117318     -0.7650658    -4.59511975
163         6  OTHER      0.1122673     -1.6627051      1.6337223    -0.02740973
>
```

### Updated tidyverse answer with one row per person_id

```
dat <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/izeh/n/master/n.csv', stringsAsFactors = F)

library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

dat %>%  arrange(person_id,item_type,item_id) %>%
     group_by(person_id,item_type) %>% 
     mutate(item_seq = seq_along(item_type)) %>%
     ungroup() %>% 
     mutate(item_type = sprintf("%s_%02d",item_type,item_seq)) %>%
     pivot_wider(id_cols = c("person_id", "gender"),
                    names_from = item_type,
                    values_from = item_trans) -> wide_dat
```

...and the output, a data frame with 2,000 rows and 37 columns.

```
> head(wide_dat)
# A tibble: 6 x 37
  person_id gender audio_vocab_01 audio_vocab_02 audio_vocab_03 audio_vocab_04
      <int> <chr>           <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl>
1         1 MALE            1.54           1.63           0.470         3.05  
2         2 MALE            3.05           3.11           3.05          3.05  
3         3 FEMALE          1.63           1.63           1.07          1.63  
4         4 FEMALE          3.05           1.63           1.07          1.36  
5         5 MALE           -1.66           0.612         -0.765        -4.60  
6         6 OTHER           0.112         -1.66           1.63         -0.0274
# … with 31 more variables: audio_vocab_05 <dbl>, audio_vocab_06 <dbl>,
#   ctest_01 <dbl>, ctest_02 <dbl>, ctest_03 <dbl>, ctest_04 <dbl>,
#   ctest_05 <dbl>, ctest_06 <dbl>, dictation_01 <dbl>, dictation_02 <dbl>,
#   dictation_03 <dbl>, dictation_04 <dbl>, dictation_05 <dbl>,
#   dictation_06 <dbl>, elicited_speech_01 <dbl>, elicited_speech_02 <dbl>,
#   elicited_speech_03 <dbl>, elicited_speech_04 <dbl>, elicited_speech_05 <dbl>,
#   elicited_speech_06 <dbl>, text_vocab_01 <dbl>, text_vocab_02 <dbl>,
#   text_vocab_03 <dbl>, text_vocab_04 <dbl>, text_vocab_05 <dbl>,
#   text_vocab_06 <dbl>, text_vocab_07 <dbl>, elicited_speech_07 <dbl>,
#   dictation_07 <dbl>, audio_vocab_07 <dbl>, ctest_07 <dbl>
>
```

### Original answer

An answer using the tidyverse is:

```
dat <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/izeh/n/master/n.csv', stringsAsFactors = F)

library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
dat %>%  arrange(person_id,item_type,item_id) %>%
     group_by(person_id,item_type) %>% 
     mutate(item_seq = seq_along(item_type)) %>%
     pivot_wider(id_cols = c("person_id", "gender","item_type"),
                    names_from = item_seq,
                    names_prefix = "measurement",
                    values_from = item_trans) -> wide_dat
```

...and the output:

```
> head(wide_dat)
# A tibble: 6 x 10
# Groups:   person_id, item_type [6]
  person_id gender item_type measurement1 measurement2 measurement3 measurement4
      <int> <chr>  <chr>            <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>
1         1 MALE   audio_vo…        1.54          1.63        0.470         3.05
2         1 MALE   ctest            0.904         2.20        1.39          1.67
3         1 MALE   dictation        5.09          5.09       -3.67          5.09
4         1 MALE   elicited…        1.83          1.07        2.39          2.27
5         1 MALE   text_voc…        2.39          3.68        2.32          1.97
6         2 MALE   audio_vo…        3.05          3.11        3.05          3.05
# … with 3 more variables: measurement5 <dbl>, measurement6 <dbl>,
#   measurement7 <dbl>
>
```

### Explanation

The input data frame includes five columns, including a person identifier, gender, an item type, an item identifier, and a value.

The desired output is a wide format data frame where each row includes three key variables (person_id, gender, and item_type) and columns representing the first through n-th observation of a given item type.

Since the `item_id` variable varies from 1 - 16,004, we can't use it as an index to create the column names. To create an index that will vary from 1 and the maximum number of measurements taken for each combination of `person_id` and `item_type`, we sort the data by `person_id`, `item_type`, and `item_id`, add a `group_by()`, and create sequential numbers to represent measurement id with `seq_along()`.

The newly created index variable, `item_seq` varies between 1 and 7, the maximum number of unique measurements for a `person_id`, `item_type` combination.

Comment: @user7148318 -- see updated solution that now includes 37 columns, seven for each `item_type` since the maximum number of measurements per person for each measurement type is 7, and there are 5 measurement types.

Comment: @user7148318 - since `item_id` seems to be monotonically increasing but not sequential within each combination of  `person_id` and `item_type`, I used it as the third item in the sorting priority: `person_id`, `item_type`, and then `item_id`. At that point I could assign `item_seq` to start at 1 for each combination of `person_id` and `item_type`. If the answer was helpful, please accept it and upvote. Thanks!

Comment: @user7148318 -  Would you please provide an explanation of what `item_id` means? What is it supposed to represent? Both `reshape()` and `pivot_wider()` need information to uniquely identify a row / column position in the output data file. Since `item_id` varies between 1 and 16,004, using it to create the output would have resulted in a data frame with over 16,000 columns (and a huge percentage of empty cells). Since the maximum number of times a particular `item_type` was measured for a `person_id`, I replaced `item_id` with `item_seq`, greatly reducing the size of the output data frame.

Comment: @user7148318 -- interesting... How do you plan to use this information? It looks like the median number of times a specific `item_id` was used is 3.0, the 75th percentile is 5.0, and the maximum is 347.

Comment: @user7148318 - I created a frequency table of `item_id` and ran `summary()`.  `itemIds <- as.data.frame(table(dat$item_id));
summary(itemIds$Freq)`

Comment: @user7148318 - yes, as noted in my earlier comment.

Comment: @user7148318 - what do you mean, "how `item_id` vary within `person_id`?